# Values with decimal are being round off in C programs

Tags: c

I have written a program in C language which has a function of broadcast_send and a broadcast_receive. The function are actually in two different files where the sending one will send a message containing a value with decimal place and the receiving one will receive the value and perform some type of calculation before presenting it on the screen. The values along with the decimal place are being sent as a message (char) and receive as a message on the other side. When I am trying to convert the message from char to float or even double, the values are being round off with no decimal place. Please find below extracts of the codes:

**Broadcast_Send:**

```
static uint16_t value = 0;

char temp_value [6];

static struct etimer et;

value = 27.34;

sprintf(temp_value, value); // converting the uint_16t to char

packetbuf_copyfrom(temp_value, 6);

broadcast_send(&broadcast);

printf("This is a test = %s C\n", temp_value); // temp_value contains the value with decimal place
```

**Broadcast_receive**

```
static uint16_t value_temp;

static uint16_t avg = 0;

static uint16_t sum = 0;

static int x = 0;

Static void broadcast_recv(struct broadcast_conn *c, const linkaddr_t *from) {

           value_temp = atof (packetbuf_dataptr());
           printf("Temperature = %u C\n", value_temp);
    }
}
```

As results:

I am getting `Temperature = 27 C`. Whereas my desirable value should be 27.34

Please help me out on this.

Best Regards,

A

Comment: `static uint16_t value_temp;` This defines `value_temp` as an integer. Integers don't have decimals.

Comment: I have tried float value_temp and even double value_temp. When I tried this, I don't see the message (values) received.

I get the below results:
Temperature =  C

Comment: No one can guess what you tried or why it failed, unless you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65032822/edit) the question and post the code. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) C11 standard. Take inspiration from existing code on [github](https://github.com/). Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Compile your code with all warnings and debug info, like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems.

As mentioned, uint16_t is an integer and does not have decimal places. You need a float, or store the temperature as an integer multiple like 2734 and divide it by 100 later.

Second, [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) takes a string to output to, a format, and values to fill in. You're passing the output string, but no format. It's using the value as the format.

Here is the correct use.

```
double value = 27.34;
sprintf(temp_value, "%.2f", value)
```

Watch out. A value of 1234.56 will overflow temp_value. `snprintf` will protect against that.

```
snprintf(temp_value, sizeof(temp_value), "%.2f", value);
```

Comment: Hello Schwern,\

Comment: @AzharHossen Hello.

Comment: Hello Schwern,

Thank you for spotting the errors. Actually I am taking raw values from Temperature sensor and storing the value in unit_16t. Then I am converting the same as shown below and storing it in char for transmission: sprintf(temp_value, "%d.%02d", value / 100, value % 100);

I have checked with a printf and temp_value in Broadcast_Send contains the decimal place. It is on the Broadcast_receive which is failing. I tried converting it back to a float / double, but I don't seeing the received value. If I put unit16_t instead of float or double, I see the number round off.

Comment: Broadcast_receive also you have the same `static uint16_t value_temp;` try changing it to `float` or `double` and print using `%f` or `%lf`